# How to convert a string to integer so i can XOR it with another integer in python

Tags: python, hex, xor

I have two files `msg.log` and `key.log` which the first file contains a plain text `Hello World!` and the `key.log` contains a string which is hex `95274DE03C78B0BDEDFBEB0D`, I want to do a bitwise XOR between these two files, but first file `msg.log` needs to be converted to ASCII first.
I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def main():
    with open ("msg.log", "r") as myfile1:
        a=myfile1.read()
    with open ("key.log", "r") as myfile2:
        b=myfile2.read()
    rr=convert_to_ascii(a)

    xored = xor_strings(a, b)
    print(xored)

def convert_to_ascii(text):
    return "".join(format(ord(char),"x") for char in text)
def xor_strings(xs, ys):
    return "".join(format(ord(x)^y) for x, y in zip(xs, ys))

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

and I get the error that `int` and `str` can not be XOR-ed, i tried to use `int(y,base=16)` function but it changes the values, while i just want to change the type and not a conversion of values in bases. what could be the solution?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think `int(y, base=16)` changes the values? https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/0e2966c9b67cb372e00c

Comment: from the result of xor i know that it has changed its value

Comment: @JohnSmith that doesnt make sense  ... of coarse an xor changes a value ...

Comment: i mean that result of xor is not the one i get when i am doing it manually,so the only part which could be wrong is the conversion of `key`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `ord` the second string. As pointed out in the comments, this is not the output you want. You need to convert the hex string into integer and then your xor will work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def main():
    with open ("msg.log", "r") as myfile1:
        a=myfile1.read()
    with open ("key.log", "r") as myfile2:
        b=myfile2.read()
    rr=convert_to_ascii(a)

    xored = xor_strings(a, b)
    print(xored)

def convert_to_ascii(text):
    return "".join(format(ord(char),"x") for char in text)
def xor_strings(xs, ys):
    intlist = [int(ys[i:i+2], base=16) for i in range(0,len(ys),2)]
    return "".join(format(ord(x)^y) for x, y in zip(xs, intlist))

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: this is pretty much guaranteed not to be what he wants ... (he has a hex string)

Comment: yes my 2nd string is already converted to hex, just its type is string which needs to be int

Comment: Indeed -- the 2nd string just needs to be converted before XOR. Code edit coming...

Answer (score 0):

you are confused about numbers vs their representations

```
hex_str = "ABC123"
int_value = int(hex_str,16)
xor_value = int_value ^ xor_with_me
print hex(xor_value)
```

you may want to take it in bytes to xor it (its not clear from the question)

```
hex_str = "ABC123"
bytes_str = binascii.unhexlify(hex_str) # becomes "\xab\xc1\x23"
byte_values = [ord(x)^xor_with_me for x in bytes_str] 
xored_bytes = "".join(chr(x) for x in byte_values)
print binascii.hexlify(xored_bytes)
```